# Create zebra striping effect on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add zebra strips to the table by using following code but its not working. When used inspect element the border of the table is not working. And also cannot see the zebra effect on the table.

```
<body>
    <div class="table_style">
        <table border="true">
            <tr>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Marks in Science</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Janet</td>
                <td>85.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>David</td>
                <td>92.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Arthur</td>
                <td>79.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bill</td>
                <td>82.00</td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
</body>
```

```css
.table_style {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #D0FSA9;
    padding: 5px;
}
table tr th {
    border: 1px solid #D0FSA9;
    padding: 5px;
}
.zebra {
    background-color: #D0FSA9;
}
.zebra1{
    background-color: #E0FSA0;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:odd").addClass("zebra");
    $("tr:even").addClass("zebra1");
});
```

Comment: your hex values are invalid ,see demo here http://jsfiddle.net/6rg90rfz/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Plain css will do this.... no Javascript is needed

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nth-child(even)` instead of using jQuery.

Also, your hex values are invalid that's why he is not applying the color.

Why are they invalid ? Because they have an `S` on it. 
The only valid characters in a hex color are: 
`0`, `1,` `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`

So, use `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` and apply valid hex values in the colors.

```css
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}

table tr:first-child {
  background-color: transparent; /*headers*/
}
```

```html
<div class="table_style">
  <table border="true">
    <tr>
      <th>Student Name</th>
      <th>Marks in Science</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Janet</td>
      <td>85.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>David</td>
      <td>92.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Arthur</td>
      <td>79.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bill</td>
      <td>82.00</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks..actually just hex value change was enough..it worked.

Comment: @PriyankaMaurya but there is no need to use jQuery, use CSS only. Its better.

Answer (score 0):

- It will not work because you used 'S' in the rgb.
- RGB only range from A TO F and 0 to 9
- just change the background color of class zebra and zebra1

```css
.table_style {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr td {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #D0F3A9;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr th {
  border: 1px solid #D0F3A9;
  padding: 5px;
}
.zebra {
  /*background-color: #D0F3A9;*/
  background-color: blue;
}
.zebra1{
  /*background-color: #D0ffA9;*/
  background-color: green;
}
```